# How to tackle the warning in ode command of desolve package in R?

Tags: r, data-modeling, ode, desolve

I have tried to write this which is otherwise fine but I do not know what is the reason I am getting the error.

```
DLSODA-  At T (=R1), too much accuracy requested  
      for precision of machine..  See TOLSF (=R2) 
In above message, R1 = 1, R2 = nan
 
  time    S  I  R     B
1    0 9999  1  0 1e+06
2    1   NA NA NA    NA
3    1   NA NA NA    NA
```

This is the output I am getting.

I have tried to run this code and it doesnot look to have any problem for me .I am adding my code in the next line. Can anyone tell me the reason of this error ?

```
library(deSolve)  
t=30
beta=0.058
gamma=1.4*exp(-6)
N=10000
state=c(S=N-1,I=1,R=0,B=10^6)
time<-seq(from=0, to =t,by=1)
parameters <- c(mu=5.089041e-05,phi=0.2,g=-0.33,xi=10,K=1e6,omega=0.00137,
                beta=beta,gamma=gamma)
model1<- function(parameters,state,time){
  with(as.list(c(parameters,state)), {
    N=state['S']+state['I']+state['R']  
    dS=(parameters['mu']*N)- (parameters['beta']*state['S']*state['I']/N)- 
      (parameters['gamma']*state['B']*state['S']/(state['B']+parameters['K']))-(parameters['mu']*state['S']) +
      (parameters['omega']*state['R'])
    
    dI=(parameters['beta']*state['S']*state['I']/N) + 
      (parameters['gamma']*state['B']*state['S']/(state['B']+parameters['K']))-(parameters['mu']*state['I'])   -
      (parameters['phi']*state['I'])
    
    dR=(parameters['phi']*state['I'])-(parameters['mu']*state['R']) -(parameters['omega']*state['R'])
    
    dB=(parameters['xi']*state['I'])-(parameters['g']*state['B'])
       
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR, dB))) 
  })
}

output <- as.data.frame(ode(y = state,  times = time,func = model1, parms = parameters ))
```

The warning messages are as follows :

```
Warning messages:
1: In lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) :
  Excessive precision requested.  scale up `rtol' and `atol' e.g by the factor 10
2: In lsoda(y, times, func, parms, ...) :
  Returning early. Results are accurate, as far as they go
```

Any kind of help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is gamma really `1.4*exp(-6)` or is that a mistranslation of `1.4e-6` which stands for `1.4*10^-6`?

Comment: Your state has values N=1e4 to B=1e6, the default absolute tolerance might be too small. // Can you explore what happened to the state values shortly before the warning? Any very large values, deviations into impossible values like negative ones, ... ?

Answer (score 1):

The main error was, that the order of arguments in the `model1`-function was wrong, it needs to be always in a fixed order `time`, `state`, `parms` as written in the help file. This fixed order is necessary for performance reasons.

Besides this, I simplified the style to improve readability. If the `with()`-function is used anyway, names of the parameter and state variables can be directly accessed, as long as there are no duplicates. In addition, I replaced the assignment `=` to `<-` and removed the `as.data.frame` in the interest of the built-in `plot` method.

Please check yourself, whether `gamma` should be `1.4*exp(-6)` (0.00347) or `1.4e-6` (0.0000014).

```r
library(deSolve)  
t     <- 30
beta  <- 0.058
#gamma <- 1.4*exp(-6)
gamma <- 1.4e-6
N     <- 10000

state=c(S=N-1, I=1, R=0, B=1e6)

time<-seq(from=0, to = 30, by=1)

parameters <- c(mu=5.089041e-05,phi=0.2,
                g=-0.33,xi=10,K=1e6,omega=0.00137,
                beta=beta,gamma=gamma)

model1 <- function(time, state, parameters){
  with(as.list(c(parameters, state)), {
    
    N <- S+I+R  
    dS <- mu*N - beta*S*I/N - gamma*B*S/(B+K) - mu*S + omega*R
    dI <- beta*S*I/N + gamma*B*S/(B+K) - mu*I - phi*I
    dR <- phi*I - mu*R - omega*R
    dB <- xi*I - g*B
    
    return(list(c(dS, dI, dR, dB))) 
  })
}

output <- ode(y = state,  times = time,func = model1, parms = parameters)

plot(output)
```